# Walk a tree with generator?

Tags: python, tree, generator, spacy

trying to walk a tree as generator, but it seems the walk stops at level1.
'table' and 'of' children are not visited !!

(Could it be because .children is itself generator ? )

```
def walk(token):
yield token
print token , '->', list(token.children)
for t in token.children :
    yield t
    walk(t)


 In [174]: doc
 Out[174]: the table is made of wood

 In [175]: list(walk(root(doc)))
 made -> [table, is, of]
 Out[175]: [made, table, is, of]

 In [176]: doc[1]
 Out[176]: table

 In [178]: list(doc[1].children)
 Out[178]: [the]

 In [181]: doc[4]
 Out[181]: of

 In [182]: list(doc[4].children)
 Out[182]: [wood]
```

========================

this question is not duplicate.

As I mentioned .children is also generator.

This seems to work, so far :

```
def walk(token):
    yield token
#   print token , '->', list(token.children)
    for t in token.children :
        for tc in walk(t) : yield tc



In [234]: list(walk(root(doc)))
Out[234]: [made, table, the, is, of, wood]
```

Comment: if this is not a school class or homework assignment, feel free to download my implementation from http://ipal.net/free/ftrgenk.py

Comment: generators call generators all the time.  that would not be a cause of incomplete results.  do you get the whole tree if you just print instead of yield?

Comment: my implementation is only tested on Python3.

Comment: How is this different from the other question it was marked as a duplicate of?